# Remove links from a webView with html content parsed with Jsoup in Android

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

I want to remove the following line:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlpd_lnkBackToList"
   href="/Nomothetiko-Ergo/dailyplan?more=true">
   Δείτε όλες τις ημερήσιες διατάξεις
</a>
```

( http://www.hellenicparliament.gr/Nomothetiko-Ergo/dailyplan ) from which I am taking the whole contents of "middlecolumnwide" div

and the FragmentActivity

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();
doc.select("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlpd_lnkBackToList").remove();
doc.outputSettings().charset("Windows-1252");
Elements ele = doc.select("div#middlecolumnwide");
...
```

I tried many of other posts with similar content, but unfortunately can't find my mistake or a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an element by it's `id` you have to use the `#` prefix. Your `select` is actually querying for an *element* with that name. This should work:

```
doc.select("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlpd_lnkBackToList").remove()
```

For details see the [Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) docs.